# Replace current string with found pattern

Tags: linux, sed

I am having some line, e. g.

```
abcds1024saaf56safas
```

I need to find first occurrence of numbers and change all line with it.

```
abcds1024saaf56safas -> 1024
```

I tried to do as follows:

```
echo asc213 | sed -r '/[0-9]+/ c\&'
```

But it seems that & is a special symbol only for s command in sed. Is there any workaround here?

Comment: You can also do it using grep, assuming your grep supports `-o` (on Linux it does): `egrep -o "^[^0-9]*[0-9]+" | egrep -o "[0-9]+"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you want to do a substitution command:

```
 echo asc123bffd | sed 's/^[^0-9]*\([0-9]*\).*$/\1/'
```

This will find the first occurrence of a number sequence and replace the whole line with the matched string of numbers.

Ok lets break it up

the s command is a substitution and looks like s/  < pattern to find >/ < pattern to replace > /

because you want to replace the whole line we have to create a pattern that will match the whole line. otherwise what ever is not matched will not be changed.

The matching pattern is ^[^0-9]*\([0-9]*\).*$

the first ^: means the beginning of the line (it is not necessary but good practice to make sure it will match from the beginning)

Now we want to match any character that is NOT a number that pattern for that is [^0-9]

[] is a set for example [abc123] says to match only abc123

when ^ is the first character in between [] it mean match anything that is NOT one of the characters listed.
the 0-9 inside [] means all characters between 0 and 9 (you could also use a-z for all lower case letters)

so [^0-9] is the same as [^0123456789] and says match anything that is not 0123456789.

the * says: match 0 or more characters like the one before so 1* will match an empty string or 1 or 11 or 111111111, abc* will match ab, abc, abcc, abccccc.
In our care it will mach any number of characters that are NOT 123456789

Note: * is "greedy" which means it will try as match the longest possible string it can, in the case of abc* if you have abccccd it will match abcccc not abc it will always try and consume as many c as it can.

the \( \) those are markers that tells sed to give a group number for the part of the string that matches the pattern described inside. the first \( \) in the pattern will be numbered 1, the second 2... etc up to 9. the group 0 is the whole pattern. You can then reuse this string in other parts of you pattern by using \1 for the first group \2 for the second etc.. \0 will print everything the whole pattern matches.

the pattern inside the \( \) is going to be the part we are interested with so a string of only numbers this is done using [0-9]*

[0-9] will match only the character 0123456789 and * says to match the longest string of digits.

that string of digits because it is in the first \( \) will be in stored group 1.

after that we do not care about what is left, but we want to make sure that the pattern consumes ALL remaining characters.

the . matches ANY character and therefore .* will match any string that comes after the list of digit..

The $ is the marker for end of line just like ^ in this case is not necessary but I always add it for completeness. but you could use it to match only the character "a" at the end of a line with "a$" for example.

now for the replacement pattern, we want to print the string of digits that were captured in group 1. the syntax for that is \1.

Does that make more sense?

Sed is a VERY powerful tool, but does take a little bit of getting used to.
there are some good resources online to learn the subtleties some that I like are:

http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html

http://www.catonmat.net/blog/sed-one-liners-explained-part-one/

Comment: @Yevs does that make more sense

Comment: I've come to a similar solution `sed -r "s/[^0-9]*([0-9]+).*/\1/"`

Comment: yep.. though with your pattern if there is a line with no digits then it will be printed unaltered.. with the * it would print an empty line.. not great.. :) but we could avoid that issue for both our cases to using sed -n 's/../../p' in which case the pattern space is not printed unless the match is made ;)

Comment: sorry I meant to say in your case.. since the patter with * would always match the line it would always print an empty line.